# RequestFactory's Entity Relationships

Tags: gwt, request, requestfactory, gwt2

The details of the `Request`'s with() implementation of `RequestFactory` in `GWT` is a bit unclear to me. See here for [the official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#relationships).

*Question 1:*

> When querying the server, RequestFactory does not automatically
>   populate relations in the object graph. To do this, use the with()
>   method on a request and specify the related property name as a String.

Does this mean that if the `Entity` at the server uses `Lazy Fetching`, the returned `EntityProxy` will have all the requested objects specified in with()? It seems a bit odd to instantiate the whole object graph of the Object server side, to only send a small piece to the client.

*Question 2:*

Does req.with("foo").with("foo"); do the same as req.with("foo"); ?

*Question 3:*

Does req.with("foo").with("bar"); do the same as req.with("foo","bar"); ?

NOTE: I'm having a really hard time finding the implementation details of with() in the source code and the [API](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/Request.html) doesn't help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

It probably depends on your server side implemenation. 
The `with` invocation will only make sure that the corresponding getter (`getFoo()`) is called shortly before the `RF` call returns to the client.

That's the reason why you also have to make sure to use an `OpenSessionInView` pattern, otherwise you might run into `NullPointeterException`s.

Question 2:

I guess the `Request<T>` implements a builder pattern. 
The end-result will be the same. 
However I am not sure if the `getter()` will be called twice or if the `with` method will check if the getter is already requested.

Question 3:

Yes it's the same.

As a sidenote. You can use `req.with("foo.bar")`. 
On the backend this will lead to a `getFoo().getBar()` call.

Comment: Concerning the first question, consider the case where the back-end runs a NoSQL Database with no eager loading facilities,e.g.: MongoDB. One could store the Object Graph there easily and get the complete graph in a java object fast. If the client would request that object (via a proxy) without any with() calls, would I have the  complete Object graph on the client side? If understood correctly it will because no extra getters are needed to fill in the object graph.

Comment: Also maybe someone can point to the documentation of the implementation of Request? with http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/class-use/Request.html it seems there is none

Comment: @Ümit: for Q2 and Q3, the answer is yes, and the _property references_ are a `Set` so there can be no duplicates (and no duplicate call to the getter on the server-side)

Comment: @GWT4Ever: RF doesn't care what your domain object behaves, it only sees its getters and setters. If a proxy's getter type is another proxy, then you need to use `with()` to get the property on the client-side; it doesn't matter whether your underlying field (or whatever) is already or lazily populated.